# Definition of dependence in probability

Tags: probability, definition, independence

[Here](https://www.wyzant.com/resources/lessons/math/statistics_and_probability/probability/further_concepts_in_probability) is classical definition and example of dependent events.

"When two events are said to be dependent, the probability of one event occurring influences the likelihood of the other event. For example, if you were to draw a two cards from a deck of $52$ cards. If on your first draw you had an ace and you put that aside, the probability of drawing an ace on the second draw is greatly changed because you drew an ace the first time".

Let’s consider another scenario: Suppose I apply to a job. There are two interviews. The second interview ($B$) will take place only if I pass the first interview ($A$). So, we have probabilities of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$. Two events per se do not depend on each other because different people conduct the interviews. But $B$ will not take place if $A$ was a failure. So  $P(B)\ne P(B\mid A)$. So, can it be said that events $A$ and $B$ are dependent?

Thanks!

Comment: Your title "combinatorics problem" does not match the question or tags at all.

Comment: And of course the two events depend on eachother; you say yourself that the second interview will take place only if you pass the first. Perhaps you should clarify (for yourself) what $A$ and $B$ are; the interviews taking place, or passing the interviews?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the title confusion. I fixed it. So, if I define the event A as "Passing the first interview" and event B as "Passing the second interview", then they are independent. But if it is "passing" each stage, then they are dependent. Correct?

Comment: @John, no, you cannot pass an interview if the interview does not take place.

Comment: OK, OK. I see. Now it is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. "When two events are said to be dependent, the probability of one event occurring influences the likelihood of the other event."
2. "Let’s consider another scenario: Suppose I apply to a job. There are two interviews. The second interview (B) will take place only if I pass the first interview (A). So, we have probabilities of P(A) and P(B). Two events per se do not depend on each other because different people conduct the interviews. But B will not take place if A was a failure."

Reasoning: Event B cannot occur without event A occurring before it.

Conclusion: A and B are dependent events.

Comment: Thanks. Will you agree that this is the matter of event definition (see my reply to Servaes)?

Comment: It definitely is a matter of definition, but it also is a matter of phrasing. Reading your comment, each definition effectively means the same thing if you are defining Event A as a parameter of getting to Event B like you have above.

Comment: To be truly independent, each event cannot have an effect on the outcome of the other.

Comment: Think of A and B as two separate interviews. Passing A will not result in you gaining or losing B unless of course you add more parameters such as the time of the interviews.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @John No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most concise definition of independent events is $P(A\,\text{and}\,B)=P(A)P(B)$. In your example, constants $p,\,q$ exist for which $P(A)=p,\,P(A\,\text{and}\,B)=P(B)=q$, with independence only if $p=1$.

Answer (score 0):

We say two events $A$ and $B$ are independent if knowing that one had occurred gave us no information about whether the other had occurred is

$$P(A|B) = P(A)  $$

and

$$P(B|A) = P(B)$$

now we know

$$ P(A) = P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} $$

then

$$ P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$$

clear if they do depend on each other this is not the case